# echo certain variable from json response

Tags: php, rest, web-services

I have the following function:

```
public function create($dir, $input)
{   
    $data = ['data'=>$input];           
    $json = $this->call('POST', '/'.$dir, $data);
    return $json;
}
```

And the following code through which I send data and receive the response:

```
require_once('../Rest_smp.php');

$data["name"]               = "Test usereee";
$data["username"]           = "4533434";
$data["email"]              = "bla@email.com";
$data["spi_classified"]     = "yes";
$data["country_id"]         = 5; 
$data["timezone_id"]        = 9; 
$data["language_id"]        = 3; 
$data["status"]             = "active";

echo (new Rest_smp())->create('user', $data);
```

When I call the url the response is coming in the following format:

```
{"status":400,"status_message":"Username or email is already in use!"}
```

What I want, is to echo only the status message and put it in a condition like this:

```
if(status_message="what response is coming") {   
    do this;  
}
```

Any help or idea would be appreciated.

Comment: it's not a duplicate question because it approaches the problem different. Read it, understand it and then give your opinion.

Comment: What exactly is supposedly different? Spell it out for us so we can help you in a targeted way.